# Matlab benchmark without 3D

Tags: matlab, benchmarking

I wanted to get a rough guide on how my computer handles Matlab so I ran BENCH on my system. The bar graph plot showed that my system was rated quite low however when I took a look at the numbers I see that the only real low number is the 3D plot test. The machine I currently use will be mainly for number crunching and will have very little 3D plotting which is why I have a minimal amount invested in the video card.

Is there a way to run bench with only the first 5 tests or do I have to run all 6?

I currently use Matlab 7.8.0 (R2009A)

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own copy of the `bench` command (maybe call it `mybench`), and then edit it to remove all calls to the subfunction `bench_3d`. You may also need to slightly modify the code that displays the results, as you'll only have 5, not 6.